# Using CORS and Warden in rack app (Grape API)

Tags: ruby, rack, cors, warden, grape-api

I have a Grape-based API running as a rack application, using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to allow cross-origin requests, and [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) for authentication. CORS is working as expected, but not in cases where I invoke `env['warden'].authenticate`. In these cases, I get an "origin not allowed" response.

I believe this is due to the order of the middleware, but I'm relatively new to rack applications. [I found some information](https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2/issues/18#issuecomment-5249136) describing a similar problem with an example of how to make this work in Rails, by forcing the order of the middleware using `config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Rack::Cors do ...` but I don't know of a non-Rails equivalent.

The following is a simplified approximation of my `config.ru`:

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
end

use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :put]
    end
end

run application
```

I've tried swapping the order of the `use` directives, but either way I get same "origin not allowed" response from methods that use warden. Part of my problem is that I'm not clear on  what determines the order of the middleware in rack applications.

Is my hunch that the order of the middleware is causing this problem feasible? It seems like I'm missing something fundamental. I'd like to get rack-cors and Warden to play nicely or to find another solution to allow CORS. I tried explicitly sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but Warden seems to wipe that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same (rather annoying) thingie, ended up with doing this on my one:

on a `before do` block,

```
header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT'
```

(You may want to tweak according to `RACK_ENV` or such...)

Seems to work. Note this is not a full CORS implementation([of course its not](http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png)) but i'll wait for that `rack-cors` gem fix...

HTH

Comment: please where would this be set?

Comment: @Jatto_abdul in the controller